# How to fix onclick "not defined"

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a button to call a function using onclick.

I kept getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Mathproblems is not defined".

```js
function Mathproblems() {
  var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
  var min = document.getElementById("min").value;
  var pdf = new jsPDF({
    orientation: "portrait",
    unit: "mm",
    format: "letter"
  });

  //there is more non relevant code, I did not want to paste a whole file
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click me to get you a PDF file." onclick="Mathproblems()" />
```

Comment: can u post HTML code to?

Comment: Is the function defined before the button, i.e. higher up in the document?

Comment: yes.. it is higher then the button code... But i am pretty sure it does not matter in JS

Comment: You should also remove the brackets from your html above, as this will call the function at load time, instead of assigning it to the button's onclick

Comment: @SimonCrane what? You saying to remove the ()? That is wrong....

Comment: So means it is not in scope. So did you somehow wrap Mathproblems inside of another block?

Comment: @QWERTY u getting the error because u not close the function with '}', plz check.

Comment: @Fahim Khan i did add a "}" If you read my comment it says that

Comment: When formatting your code it is evident you are missing a `}` we do not see it and where are your commenting it?

Comment: Adding the `}` changes the error because the script does not find the min and max fields

Comment: @vipul patel sorry but getElementById() does not required #. In Jquery we required.

Answer (score -1):

you might want to get rid of your little **/**  inside your `<input>` tag instead of `<input/>` and probably check the structure to see if all the codes are wrapped correctly. The following code is the simplified structure. I assume you are not using jquery or not other libs. 
Otherwise for Jquery
you need to wrap your function inside

```
$(function() {});
```

```html
<script>
function Mathproblems() {
    var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
    var min = document.getElementById("min").value;
    console.log(max);
    console.log(min);
  }
</script>
<body>
<input id="max" value="maxvalue" >
<input id="min" value="minvalue" >
<input type="button" value="Click me to get you a PDF file." onclick="Mathproblems()">
</body>
```